# Android HERE SDK lite: Place Here logo to another

Tags: android, here-api

Is it possible to place the HERE logo in the MapviewLiteView to another place instead of the lower right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HERE SDK lite for Android doesn't offer class for LogoPosition changes. However premium does.

For more details please refer the different positions premium allow :

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-starter/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/common/CopyrightLogoPosition.html

Comment: A development JIRA is in pipeline for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Not right now, but I have checked with the team and this feature will be available with the next release.